# MIPS SW & LW negative offset

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm doing old exams to learn for an upcoming exam. However, I do not understand this question. Some help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

I understand what A, C and D is. But I can not for my life understand how to get the answer of B and E.
I don't know what is happening when SW and LW are using negative 'offset' values?

The answers are:
[image]

Comment: no different than positive offset values.  If I had some address 0x1010 and used a positive offset of 4 then that means I want 0x1014.  If I use a negative offset of 8 that means I want 0x1008.  0x3FF0 + 0x10 - 0x8 = 0x4000 - 8 = 0x3FF8.

Comment: well, after the second addi t0 = 0x4000. When SW stores t0-8 in t0, is 0x3ff8 stored in t0?

Comment: No, the value 0x4000 is stored into memory.  `sw` does not change registers; only one memory location is changed.

Comment: t0 = 0x3ff0 + 0x10 = 0x4000.  then 0x4000 + 0xC = 0x400C.  then 0x400C - 0x14 = 0x3FF8

Comment: stop looking at the picture, first figure out the assembly, which it appears you dont understand.  Once you fully understand the assembly then you can look at the picture again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please start by understanding the code

```
   40210:   20083ff0    addi    $8,$0,16368
   40214:   21080010    addi    $8,$8,16
   40218:   ad08fff8    sw  $8,-8($8)
   4021c:   2108000c    addi    $8,$8,12
   40220:   8d12ffec    lw  $18,-20($8)
```

then examine the picture, with having the answer and seeing the code you can connect the dots, granted before having the answer there would be a little more work, but either way have to fully understand the code.

```
40210:  20083ff0    addi    $8,$0,16368
$8 = 0 + 0x3FF0 = 0x00003FF0

40214:  21080010    addi    $8,$8,16
$8 = $8 + 16 = 0x3FF0 + 0x10 = 0x4000

40218:  ad08fff8    sw  $8,-8($8)
memory_address $8 - 8 = contents of $8
[0x4000 - 8] = 0x4000
[0x4000 + (-8)] = 0x4000
[0x4000 + (0xFFFFFFF7 + 1)] = 0x4000
[0x00004000 + 0xFFFFFFF8] = 0x4000
[0x00003FF8] = 0x4000

4021c:  2108000c    addi    $8,$8,12
$8 = $8 + 12 = 0x4000 + 0xC = 0x400C

40220:  8d12ffec    lw  $18,-20($8)
$18 = [$8 - 20]
$18 = [0x0000400C - 0x14]
$18 = [0x0000400C + (-0x14)]
$18 = [0x0000400C + 0xFFFFFFEC]
$18 = [0x00003FF8]
$18 = 0x4000
```

you can see the 0xFFEC in the last instruction and then the sign extension in front of A sign extends bit 15 into 0xFFFFFFEC.

B is the output of the alu 0x0000400C + 0xFFFFFFEC = 0x00003FF8

C is bits 20:16 of the instruction, 0x12, 0x12 = 18 as in $18

D is the next instruction address 0x40224

E 0x4000 the result of the read of 0x3FF8.

Understand this drawing is not a real design this is an academic exercise, but I assume you have been using this drawing for weeks/months/chapters. So you should be familiar with it after reading/understanding the code. C should be the bits from the next instruction for example or two after, not the current.  But don't try to correct the professor on this, you will lose.  The professor is right as far as school goes, after that then reality is right, or your boss/mentor.  D is wrong too, actually most of them are wrong but that's okay, use it the way it is taught, it is a visual exercise.

Good thing you had the answer otherwise we would give you the answer based on the drawing as shown rather than what you are being taught.  And that would confuse you even further.

There is no magic to the offsets

```
addi $t0,$zero,0x1010
sw $t1,-8($t0)
sw $t1,8($t0)

   0:   20081010    addi    $8,$0,4112
   4:   ad09fff8    sw  $9,-8($8)
   8:   ad090008    sw  $9,8($8)
```

so that puts 0x1010 in register $8

Then per the instruction set the offset is the lower 16 bits of the sw
instruction sign extended we see 0xFFF8 in the instruction, we sign extend
bit 15 to get 0xFFFFFFF8 add that to the value in $8, 0x00001010 you get 0x00001008.  for the third instruction same deal sign extend 0x0008 to 0x00000008 and 0x00001010+0x00000008 = 0x00001018.  Positive and negative work the same way no difference.

Answer (score 1):

`A` is the sign extended immediate value — here -20 (0xFFEC in 16-bits from the I-type immediate) after sign extending to 32-bits.  Sign extension means filling the top 16 bits of 32, with the same value as the sign bit of the 16-bit immediate, i.e. those top 16 bits are either all 0's or all 1's depending on the sign of the 16-bit immediate.  If the 16-bit immediate is negative, then filling the top 16 of 32 with 1's keeps the same value (-20).

`B` look like it is labeling the data memory bypass, which in this case holds the 32-bit effective address of the load — while this value is fed to the data memory (at DataMemory.A), this particular data path feeding to the next mux isn't consumed with `lw`.

`C` is the load's target register, `$s2`

`D` is `PC + 4` setting up for execution of the next instruction after the `lw`

`E` is the value read from memory.

Comment: well, that i understand. What i don't get is how to calculate, for example, E. I get the value to be 0x3ff0. the answer is 0x4000

Comment: You have to know what is in the memory location at the effective address.  We know what is at that memory location because the store `sw` just put it there.

Comment: I mean, the way i'm thinking is the following. Start with first addi, t0=0x3ff0. second addi, t0=0x4000. SW, i guess, subtract 8, so t0=0x3ff8. third addi then adds 12, t0=0x4004. lastly, lw makes s2=t0-20, which makes t0=0x3ff0.

Comment: `sw` does not change registers.  it changes memory only.

Comment: alright, but when LW does its thing, how can it 'find' t0 if it decrements with 20?

Comment: Now that you know how store works, follow the code from the beginning.  Identify the effective address of the `sw` to see what memory location it stores into (and remember the value that it stores there).  Then you know something, namely what value is stored is at that address.  Then follow the code to identify the effective address of the `lw`.  If it is the same address as something you already know about (it is) then you know what value memory will return for the result of the load.

Comment: We would not say that this `lw` decrements; we would say it merely subtracts, since the result of the subtraction is not kept beyond its use for DataMemory.A.  Decrementing implies updating of some state, which is not the case here with this address computation (which is technically an addition of a signed value, known to be negative in this case).